# Replace values in ndarray with condirion

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I need to change values in ndarray: if > 0.5 then 1, less - then 0. Example:

```
array([ 0.11865984,  0.49666225,  0.134077  ,  0.09502114,  0.70667432,
    0.1648032 ,  0.6356094 ,  0.36054945,  0.68379407,  0.09297716])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([ 0.11865984,  0.49666225,  0.134077  ,  0.09502114,  0.70667432,
    0.1648032 ,  0.6356094 ,  0.36054945,  0.68379407,  0.09297716])

bool_condition_array = arr > 0.5
binary_array = bool_condition_array.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Evenly round to the given number of decimals. [np.around](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html)

If you have an `np.array` you can use `np.around` function:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([ 0.11865984,  0.49666225,  0.134077  ,  0.09502114,  0.70667432,
    0.1648032 ,  0.6356094 ,  0.36054945,  0.68379407,  0.09297716])
result = np.around(arr)
print(result)
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0.])
```