# Replace arrays in ndarray based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

This question is about replacing entire arrays if they fulfil conditions. It is not about replacing individual values in an ndarray - as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61447564/replace-values-in-ndarray-with-condirion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72652131/replacing-elements-in-ndarray-based-on-condition) question for example.

---

### Problem

I have an input array `inarray`. As an example:

```
import numpy as np
inarray = \
np.array([[[1,1,1,1],
           [2,2,2,2]],
          [[3,3,3,3],
           [4,4,4,4]]])
```

I would like to replace the rows containing `[1,1,1,1]` by `[9,9,9,9]`.

I suspect there is a more efficient way of doing this than my method below. What is it?

---

### My attempt

I do:

```
inarray[np.equal(inarray,np.array([1,1,1,1])).all(axis=2)]=np.array([9,9,9,9])
```

This line changes `inarray` to be:

```
array([[[9, 9, 9, 9],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

as expected.

---

### Problem with other methods

One suggested way by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72732433/8565438) is to use:

```
inarray[inarray == [1,1,1,1]] = [9,9,9,9]
```

The problem with this is that when `[1,1,1,1]` appears multiple times, this fails:

```
inarray = \
np.array([[[1,1,1,1],
           [2,2,2,2]],
          [[1,1,1,1],
           [4,4,4,4]]])

inarray[inarray == [1,1,1,1]] = [9,9,9,9]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [81], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 inarray[inarray == [1,1,1,1]] = [9,9,9,9]

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 4 input values to the 8 output values where the mask is true
```

Expected result is `inarray` having been changed to:

```
array([[[9, 9, 9, 9],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[9, 9, 9, 9],
        [4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

Comment: Your solution has 2 parts: `mask = np.equal(inarray,np.array([1,1,1,1])).all(axis=2)`, and `inarray[mask]=value`.  A broadcasted == followed by an `all` is a common pattern in `numpy`.  The intermediate array can be large, but this makes optimal use of compiled numpy methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work

```
inarray[inarray == [1,1,1,1]] = [9,9,9,9]
```

It basically matches where inarray equals `[1,1,1,1]`and makes it `[9,9,9,9]`

### Edit

Well you can then modify slightly your code to this

```
inarray[(inarray==[1,1,1,1]).all(axis=2)]=[9,9,9,9]
```

But it really does not make a big difference

Comment: Originally my question had a typo in it (I had `[2,2,2,2]` insead of `[1,1,1,1]` at one place), sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe we can drop the `np.array()` from around `[1,1,1,1]`, idk if it has a significance.

Comment: Indeed, I changed in the answer!